# Is there a nutritional difference between Grain-Fed and Grass-Fed beef?

Tags: nutrition

There are many sources that discuss the difference between grain-fed and grass-fed beef.

Many claim there is a difference in the nutritional characteristics of the beef.

Does the diet of a cow have any influence on the nutrition of the end product that you may eat?

Comment: Calling this "the old grain-fed vs grass-fed debate" seems to mischaracterise the debate, which is generally about which is better (according to various criteria, including animal welfare, environmental, and nutrition) not whether there is a difference at all.

Comment: While I do grant that there are people making that claim the standard on this website is still to provide a citation to an outside source making the claim and I think that would improve the question.

Comment: @Christian That is not the standard. The standard is notable, clear, objective, and narrowly tailored.

Comment: Protip: Grass fed beef is tough and chewy, so tenderize it

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yes, there is a difference [1], and the longer the cattle are finished with grain, the greater the differences appears to be [2]

> Grass-based diets have been shown to enhance total conjugated linoleic
>   acid (CLA) (C18:2) isomers, trans vaccenic acid (TVA) (C18:1 t11), a
>   precursor to CLA, and omega-3 (n-3) FAs on a g/g fat basis. While the
>   overall concentration of total SFAs is not different between feeding
>   regimens, grass-finished beef tends toward a higher proportion of
>   cholesterol neutral stearic FA (C18:0), and less cholesterol-elevating
>   SFAs such as myristic (C14:0) and palmitic (C16:0) FAs. Several
>   studies suggest that grass-based diets elevate precursors for Vitamin
>   A and E, as well as cancer fighting antioxidants such as glutathione
>   (GT) and superoxide dismutase (SOD) activity as compared to grain-fed
>   contemporaries. Fat conscious consumers will also prefer the overall
>   lower fat content of a grass-fed beef product. [1]

However, in the amount of meat that one might ordinarily consume and with the normal food preparation of removing visible fat, the effect on your health may not be that much different.  I don't think the hypothesis that grass fed is better (or less bad) for cardiovascular health has been tested in prospective trials yet.

[1] Daley CA, Abbott A, Doyle PS, Nader GA, Larson S. [A review of fatty acid profiles and antioxidant content in grass-fed and grain-fed beef.](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/20219103) Nutr J 2010 Mar 10;9:10. doi: 10.1186/1475-2891-9-10. PubMed PMID: 20219103.

[2] Ponnampalam EN, Mann NJ, Sinclair AJ. [Effect of feeding systems on omega-3 fatty acids, conjugated linoleic acid and trans fatty acids in Australian beef cuts: potential impact on human health.](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/16500874) Asia Pac J Clin Nutr. 2006;15(1):21-9. PubMed PMID: 16500874.

Comment: Are there any studies on the levels of vitamins and minerals in the meat of grass-fed vs grain-fed cows? Or only this research on fats and antioxidants? It makes intuitive sense that if cows can't properly digest grains, they may have a shortage of some of these nutrients. But just because it sounds true doesn't mean it is.